# Linking nodes using views

Tags: views

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to display multiple content types in a page using views.

In my example I have a music studio.

I have a content type for user including basic personal info

I have a content type for studio including room capabilities

And finally I have a content type for computer including hardware specs.

I'd like to have all this viewable on a page together so that when a user views a studio they see the user (engineer) and the computer information.

I'm very slightly familiar with entity ref but it appears to only show the title of the node when viewing and I'd like to have a page with composite information containing fields I select from each node/content type

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Entity reference and relationship

- Create a views of studio.
- Make a relationship of Entity reference with user and hardware information
- Now when you select fields all the fields from user, studio and hardware will be available in the list.
- Select those fields which you need. and that's it.

Comment: Is relationship a module or something in the editing area of views?

Comment: no, its views default functionality. Click the right corned under contextual filter there is a tab named relationship